# Problems with SQL Query and alias

Tags: sql-server

Can somebody tell me why this is complaining?
I am using SQL Server, with one table called test and 1 column called word

This is my query:

```
SELECT TOP 1
COUNT(*) AS count, 
(LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word,'A',''))) AS letters
FROM dbo.TEST 
WHERE 
word LIKE '******' 
GROUP BY letters 
ORDER BY count DESC
```

THis is the result error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
Invalid column name 'letters'.
```

Why is complaining about my alias?

Comment: See [Logical Processing Order of the Select statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189499.aspx). `GROUP BY` runs fifth. `SELECT` runs eighth. And "because the SELECT clause is step 8, any column aliases or derived columns defined in that clause cannot be referenced by preceding clauses"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use alias in the GROUP BY, use the same calculated column:

```
SELECT TOP 1
COUNT(*) AS count, 
(LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word,'A',''))) AS letters
FROM dbo.TEST 
WHERE 
word LIKE '******' 
GROUP BY (LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word,'A','')))
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an alias in the GROUP BY clause.
This is due to SQL processing order, GROUP BY is processed before SELECT.
Try replacing:

```
GROUP BY letters
```

with

```
GROUP BY (LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word,'A','')))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an alias within a query. What you need is:

```
SELECT TOP 1
COUNT(*) AS count, 
(LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word,'A',''))) AS letters
FROM dbo.TEST 
WHERE 
word LIKE '******' 
GROUP BY (LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word,'A','')))
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Change the group by in the query

```
   SELECT TOP 1
            COUNT(*) AS count ,
            ( LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word, 'A', '')) ) AS letters
    FROM    dbo.TEST
    WHERE   word LIKE '******'
    GROUP BY ( LEN(word) - LEN(REPLACE(word, 'A', '')) )
    ORDER BY count DESC
```